# PHPUnit test not executing

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I am trying to execute some test in PHPUnits but it's not getting executed.

```
<?php

use \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class UserControllerTest extends TestCase {

    public function testThatCanGetNumber() {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('UserModel')
            ->setMethods(array('getNumber'))
            ->getMock();

        $mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getNumber')
            ->with($this->equalTo(5));
    }
}
```

However, if I extend the class with `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` it gets executed. Why is that?

This is my `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         verbose="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: PHPUnit switched to namespaces at version 6. You either need to use a PHPUnit version >= 6 with \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase or a PHPUnit version <= 5 with PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.

Comment: Both PHPUnit 4 and PHPUnit 5 have a forward compatibility layer that allow the usage of both the old `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` as well as the new `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` class name.

Comment: I will have to yield to the author on this one heh. :)

Comment: @SebastianBergmann So what would be the solution? I am using PHPunit 6.4 (stable version). Because using `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` doesn't allow me to use `$this->getMockBuilder('UserModel')` which also causes an error saying `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockBuilder::__construct() must be an instance of PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

Answer (score 0):

You expect that the method is getting called but you are not executing anything in the test. You should call the method where the mocked method is called.